# Code to create IIS Website

Tags: iis, iis-7

I need to programatically create an IIS website. Can anybody show me the code to do this?

Comment: The best place for information on IIS 7, that I found so far is [here](http://learn.iis.net/)

Answer (score 4):

Please don't use WMI (`DirectoryEntry`) if at all possible when targeting IIS 7 or above. There is an API called [`ServerManager`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.web.administration.servermanager%28v=VS.90%29.aspx) in the `Microsoft.Web.Administration.dll` (`windows\system32\inetsrv`) that makes this really easy:

```
ServerManager serverManager = new ServerManager();
serverManager.Sites.Add("Mysite", "c:\temp\", 8080);
```

Answer (score 2):

This will work for IIS 6.0 and later, it's written in VB.Net (which, this is small enough to easily to convert to C# if needed).  I also didn't write this, I found it here (I did compile it though to make sure it would build): http://www.gafvert.info/notes/VBNET-Create-Website-IIS6.htm

#### VB Version

```
Imports System.DirectoryServices
Imports System

Public Class IISAdmin
    Public Shared Function CreateWebsite(webserver As String, serverComment As String, serverBindings As String, homeDirectory As String) As Integer
        Dim w3svc As DirectoryEntry
        w3svc = New DirectoryEntry("IIS://localhost/w3svc")

        'Create a website object array
        Dim newsite() As Object
        newsite = New Object(){serverComment, new Object(){serverBindings}, homeDirectory}

        'invoke IIsWebService.CreateNewSite
        Dim websiteId As Object
        websiteId = w3svc.Invoke("CreateNewSite", newsite)

        Return websiteId

    End Function

    Public Shared Sub Main(args As String())
        Dim a As Integer
        a = CreateWebsite("localhost", "Testing.com", ":80:Testing.com", "C:\\inetpub\\wwwroot")
        Console.WriteLine("Created website with ID: " & a)
    End Sub

End Class
```

#### C# Version

```
public static int CreateWebsite(string webserver, string serverComment, string serverBindings, string homeDirectory)
{
   DirectoryEntry w3svc = new DirectoryEntry("IIS://localhost/w3svc");

   //Create a website object array
   object[] newsite = new object[]{serverComment, new object[]{serverBindings}, homeDirectory};

   //invoke IIsWebService.CreateNewSite
   object websiteId = (object)w3svc.Invoke("CreateNewSite", newsite);

   return (int)websiteId;
}
```

Comment: I also suspect this will need to be run from the web-server because it points to IIS://localhost  

Not sure how it would work remotely, it would depend on your security setup.

Comment: @ Kirtan.   Hehe.  :)  I usually don't post here, was a fluke, I saw the question and thought, I know I've seen that done somewhere, hehe.

Comment: Please stay away from WMI for IIS 7 and above, there are simpler/faster/better/more-reliable/ ways of doing it using ServerManager