# What is the best way to create a website in IIS through coding

Tags: iis

What is the best way to create a website in IIS 6.0 programmatically? like if i want my application to take a name of a website and create it in IIS, what would i need to do in ASP.Net?

Comment: Check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/769064/code-to-create-iis-website

Answer (score -1):

- An ASp.NET hosting accoun twith admin permissions (as otherwise your scripts fail)
- Code to manipulate the IIS metabase.
- A browser t oread the documentation over ad Microsoft's website ;)

Comment: I think the poster was looking for more input that essentially "Go Google It"!

Comment: So what ;) There is a TON of details in that - this is why reading the documentation is mandatory. I did not tell the user to "google it". Microsoft has detailed documentation abou the metabase in the library there. Accessible by browser.